# store and display emoji Android+PHP+MySql

Tags: php, android, mysql, emoji

In my android app, from the textview i am reading the text with emoji from the user as --

```
String textmsgGet = mTextView.getText().toString().trim();
String textmsg = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(textmsgGet);
```

And display it in another activity as --

```
String titleGet = jsonObject.getString("title");
String title = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(titleGet);
```

In my php page, while reading the value, i am using --

```
$textmsg = $_POST['textmsg'];
```

And while display, i am using 0--

```
$title = utf8_encode($data['textmsg']);
```

but in my database, the values are stored as --

```
\u1F601 hello \u1F601
```

what the thing i am missing, any help will be great. thnx

Answer (score 0):

Try converting your entire mysql database and tables character-set and collation to UTF-8 like this:

```
ALTER DATABASE databasename CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

And instead encoding the text whe you want to display, try decoding it:

```
$title = utf8_decode($data['textmsg']);
```